# C++ Specialize Inherited Template in Derived Class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

I'm trying to write a program where derived classes of ServiceWorker such as Firefighter can "confront" objects derived from class Incident (Fire, Injury, Robbery). The confrontation would return a boolean value of whether or not it succeeded. For example, a firefighter confronting a fire would be successful, but a firefighter confronting a robbery would not. ServiceWorker would track the number of confrontations and successful confrontations as well as have a confront method that will determine if the confrontation was successful.

I want to use traits to store what each derived class of ServiceWorker can confront in its class definition. However, in ServiceWorker the confront method creates the traits class, but I want to specialize it in its derived classes so each derived class only knows what it can confront.

```
class Incident { };
class Fire : Incident { };
class Robbery : Incident { };
class Injury : Incident { };

class ServiceWorker {
public:
    ServiceWorker() : ratio(0), num_success(0), num_confronts(0) {

    }

    template <typename U>
    struct can_confront {
        static const bool result = false;
    };

    double successRatio() { 
    if(ratio)
            return ratio;
        else 
            throw;
    }
    template <typename T>
    void confront(T incident) {
        if(can_confront<T>::result)
            num_success++;
        num_confronts++;

        ratio = num_success / num_confronts;
    }
protected:
    double ratio;
    unsigned int num_success;
    unsigned int num_confronts;
};

class Firefighter : public ServiceWorker {
public:
    template <>
    struct can_confront<Fire> {
        static const bool result = true;
    };
};
```

***EDIT***

So I managed to figure it out. I got rid of templates and made confront virtual, so making a derived class of ServiceWorker would only require redefining the virtual function and using ServiceWorker::confront. I also added confront_success() and calc_ratio() to make adding new ServiceWorkers easier. I made Firefighter::confront() take FirefighterIncident, which inherited from Incident. That way, adding new incidents for Firefighter would be easy since they'd only have to inherit from FirefigherIncident.

```
class Incident {};
class FirefighterIncident : public Incident {};
class Fire : public FirefighterIncident {};
class RescueCat : public FirefighterIncident {};

class ServiceWorker {
public:
    ServiceWorker() : ratio(0), num_success(0), num_confronts(0) {

    }

    double successRatio() { 
        if(num_confronts != 0)
            return ratio;
        else {
            std::cout << "Can't divide by zero in ratio!" << std::endl;
            throw;
        }
    }

    virtual void confront(const Incident&) {
        num_confronts++;
        calc_ratio();
    }
protected:
    double ratio;
    unsigned int num_success;
    unsigned int num_confronts;

    void calc_ratio() {
        ratio = num_success / (double) num_confronts;
    }

    void confront_success() {
        num_success++;
        num_confronts++;
        calc_ratio();
    }
};

class Firefighter : public ServiceWorker {
public:
    using ServiceWorker::confront;
    virtual bool confront(const FirefighterIncident&) { confront_success(); }
};
```

Comment: No you cannot do that, the only thing you can change in the derived class is a virtual function implementation and its return type (covariantly). Since `confront` is not virtual iy has no idea about derived classes' existence.

Comment: You need to have double dispatch to have `void confront(ServiceWorker&, const Incident&)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 " to have double dispatch" if runtime polymorphism is needed, that is.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, things get cleaner if you take advantage of `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`. In the base class,

```
class ServiceWorker {
public:
template <typename U>
struct can_confront: std::false_type { };
...
```

and in the derived class,

```
class Firefighter: public ServiceWorker {
public:
template<typename U>
struct can_confront: ServiceWorker::template can_confront<U> { };
...
```

Notice that I redefined `can_confront` in the derived class (through inheritance), so that I can specialize it without specializing `ServiceWorker::can_confront`. To do this, simply add

```
template<>
struct Firefighter::can_confront<Fire>: std::true_type { };
```

*outside* the class definition. The `confront` template method will then work once the `if` statement is replaced with

```
if(can_confront<T>::value)
```

*However*, remember that you're still left with the problem that `confront` always uses `ServiceWorker::can_confront<T>`, even when you call it through a `Firefighter` object. An easy fix would be to copy the definition of `confront` into each derived class.

Comment: These are probably nice improvements but they have nothing to do with the gist of the question. Copying the template to the derived cassess will not achieve anything.

Comment: @n.m. Anything besides a working code (OP's code doesn't compile) and the specialization procedure he's looking for. In my understanding, the gist of the question is exactly in specialization of `can_confront` for multiple derived classes. Polymorphism is not possible since `confront` cannot be made virtual, but it can be achieved, e.g. through overloading, if truly wanted.

Comment: Yeah so originally, I used polymorphism to make it work and each incident at a number code. The number code was checked in confront() when the incident was passed to a ServiceWorker. I thought that was really sloppy technique, but I thought I could use  traits classes to improve it. The goal of this is to keep the same polymorphic and inherited abilities while removing the need for number codes.